# Filter list 1 from list 2

Tags: c#, linq, list, filter

Im having a problem here with performance.

I got to List contains (50k items) 
and List  contains (120k items)

WholeSaleEntry is

```
public class WholeSaleEntry
{
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string Stock { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string EAN { get; set; }
}
```

and ProductList

```
public class ProductList
{
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string FinalPrice { get; set; }
    public string AlternateID { get; set; }

}
```

I need to filter WholeSaleEntry By its EAN and Its SKU in case that their EAN or SKU is in the ProductList.AlternateID 
I wrote this code which works but the performance is really slow

```
       List<WholeSaleEntry> filterWholeSale(List<WholeSaleEntry> wholeSaleEntry, List<ProductList> productList)
    {
        List<WholeSaleEntry> list = new List<WholeSaleEntry>();
        foreach (WholeSaleEntry item in wholeSaleEntry)
        {
            try
            {
                string productSku = item.SKU;
                string productEan = item.EAN;
                var filteredCollection = productList.Where(itemx => (itemx.AlternateID == productEan) || (itemx.AlternateID == productSku)).ToList();

                if (filteredCollection.Count > 0)
                {
                    list.Add(item);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Is there any better filtering system or something that can filter it in bulk?

Comment: First thought - use `Any` instead of `Where`. With where you filter all records and then checking count. With Any you stop filtering on the first match. So try `if(productList.Any(item=>...)) list.Add(item);`

Comment: I have never used it . and honestly i tried but i couldnt figure out how to implement that in my code

Comment: do i need to just change where to any or the query just something else?

Comment: I would try this:

Comment: 'List<WholeSaleEntry> filterWholeSale(List<WholeSaleEntry> wholeSaleEntry, List<ProductList> productList) {
return (from s in wholeSaleEntry
from p in productList
where s.SKU == p.SKU or s.EAN == p.AlternativeID
select s).ToList();
}'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of `.Where(...).ToList()` will find every matching item, and in the end you only need to know if there is a matching item. That can be fixed using `Any(...)` which stops as soon as a match is found, like this:

```
var hasAny = productList.Any(itemx => itemx.AlternateID == productEan || itemx.AlternateID == productSku);
if (hasAny)
{
    list.Add(item);
}
```

**Update:** the algorithm can be simplified to this. First get the unique alternate IDs using a `HashSet`, which stores duplicate items just once, and which is crazy fast for lookup. Then get all WholeSale items that match with that.
There will not be many faster strategies, and the code is small and I think easy to understand.

```
var uniqueAlternateIDs = new HashSet<string>(productList.Select(w => w.AlternateID));
var list = wholeSaleEntry
    .Where(w => uniqueAlternateIDs.Contains(w.SKU)
             || uniqueAlternateIDs.Contains(w.EAN))
    .ToList();
return list;
```

A quick test revealed that for 50k + 50k items, using `HashSet<string>` took 28ms to get the answer. Using a `List<string>` filled using `.Distinct().ToList()` took 48 seconds, with all other code the same.

Comment: Which sounds nice in theory, but is worst case still looping over all 120k items 50k times.

Comment: You'd want a `HashSet<string>` for that code in your edit, which provides faster lookup than a list.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a good plan, I just never used that so had to go with what I do know.

Comment: Did the HashSet... crazy fast indeed!

Comment: You are amazing my friend. this is awesome . its now done in less than a sec

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want a specific method and avoid the list just do this.

```
var filteredWholeSale = wholeSaleEntry.Where(x => productList.Any(itemx => itemx.AlternateID == x.EAN || itemx.AlternateID == x.SKU));
```

Comment: @CodeCaster. Fair enough, I added a reason. Still not the same solution as already provided though